# how to create graphs while running python with ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python

As Matplotlib seem not to work (what a drag it's such a nice tool) I'am looking for alternatives to create graphs while running python with ArcGIS 10. Besides regular pie and column charts I need in particular the possibility to create star plots/ radar charts / amoeba diagram - most likely something like:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/polar_bar.html

Most likely with a tool with as less as possible dependencies. 
Any recommendations are welcome

Thanks!

Comment: did you see the addin on code gallery?  http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=D2735FE6-1422-2418-A072-E314CE6BC68F

Comment: @Brad principally the idea looks nice but they tool neither seem to be able to be controlled by pythonscripting nor it seem to support any star plots / radar charts. Hopefully in future!

Answer (score 1):

Built in to arcpy is [a series of classes for making graphs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Graph/000v0000013w000000/), it may be what you need.

What of matplotlib isn't working? I know the TK parts of the UI don't play nice in the UI, but exporting to an image file and using `os.startfile` should work, or marking the tool to run out of process.

Comment: I know the possibilities of built in of Arcgis and even took into account the use of templates, but as the graph options are still a little weak (of course they got much better in the recent years) I was looking for alternatives. 
Matplotlib seemed to be the tool that would fit my needs. Unfortunatly I didnt get it run; see also my post at the ESRIForum: 
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/33772-Matplotlib-for-Python-scripting-in-ArcGIS-10-does-not-work?p=113813#post113813

Comment: Furthermore I tried it like you suggested by exporting the graph as a file. Therefore I tried this one:  

from pylab import *

plot ( arange(0,10),[9,4,5,2,3,5,7,12,2,3],'.-',label='sample1' )
plot ( arange(0,10),[12,5,33,2,4,5,3,3,22,10],'o-',label='sample2' )
xlabel('x axis')
ylabel('y axis')
title('my sample graphs')
legend(('sample1','sample2'))
savefig("c:\sampleg.png",dpi=(640/8))

Anyway if I run it with ArcGIS I still get the message: 
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named pylab
Failed to execute (Script).

Comment: By the way if I let it run in iPython (same installation) it works perfect.
If you have any suggestion how to get it run I will really appreciate this. 
Thanks!

Comment: This is interesting because Matplotlib is being bundled with 10.1 and there wasn't much we needed to do to get it working -- I'll see what's up on a 10.0 system.

Comment: This would be great as the version 10.1 is not shipped out in Germany yet, so I have to find a solution before that. 
Thanks! Werner

Comment: Jason, did I understand it right, that arcgis 10.1 comes along with matplotlib?

Comment: Responding to an old question, but I can confirm ArcGIS 10.1 does include matplotlib, but not ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: instead of `import pylab` you can use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.  Then the calls will be `plt.plot()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used ReportLab for creating Reports as PDF from Python (with ArcGIS 10) but it also has some charting/graphing capabilities: http://www.protocolostomy.com/2008/10/22/generating-reports-with-charts-using-python-reportlab/ (See Section 11.3 in its [User Guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf))

However, I think you may be looking for more complex graph types than ReportLab has been used for previously.